# how to implement jsx as a class property for downstream resolution?

Tags: reactjs

I've created the following interface:

```
export interface DataColumn {
    fieldName: string,
    columnHeaderName: string,
    fieldValue: any;
    className: string;
    headerClassName: string;
    template: JSX.Element | undefined;
}
```

The last property reflects an optional template.  If provided then it should override the default generic fieldValue display.  The goal is to render out the template in the downstream component like this:

```
{template}
```

But I'm not clear on how to instantiate the value for this property in the intermediate component.  I tried the following code:

```
template: new JSX.Element(<div>THIS IS MY JSX TEST</div>)
```

But that code returns the following error:

> Cannot use namespace 'JSX' as a value.ts(2708)

So what's the proper way to set a class property with a JSX value which can then be dynamically rendered as JSX in a downstream component?